# How to Add Class in the dropdown list in MVC4 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and I want to  add css clss in the dropdown list in below syntax with default value

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId","Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but it gives me below error

```
 CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Test.Models.M_Product>' does not 
contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload     
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, 
 object)' has some invalid arguments
```

Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory.

You're trying to put **"Select"** which is `string` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>`

Create a list of SelectListItem and pass it instead of "Select".

```
new SelectList(Model.SomeFieldWhichIsSelectListItem, "Value", "Text")
```

Comment: Weird, any more details and i will write it for you.

Comment: I want to bind dropdownlist from database with default Text and custom css ..so please give me any idea